# Can i undo this batch file?

Tags: windows, powershell

I stupidly didnt create a system restore point before running this

```
PowerCfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_PROCESSOR IDLEDISABLE 000

PowerCfg /SETACTIVE SCHEME_CURRENT

PowerCfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_PROCESSOR IDLEDISABLE 000

PowerCfg /SETACTIVE SCHEME_CURRENT
```

running it was supposed to lessen idle cpu usage but caused worse performance

Answer (score 0):

Your current script activates the idle mode of your processor which should be activated by default, it is just not directly visible in your power settings.

You have two possibilities to change these values again, if you have deactivated your idle by default.

After the mentioned batch script has run, a registry key has been created.
This is located here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\5d76a2ca-e8c0-402f-a133-2158492d58ad
```

Here you will find a value called "Atrribut" and the value is probably set to 1 (1 here for NOT SHOW).
You have to change this to 0 to show the IdleDisable power options.

Then open your power saving settings and go to the advanced settings.

Now you will find a tab called Disable Processor Idle under the item Processor Power Management.

Here you can undo your entry by deactivating the idle (Default = Enable idle).
But as said before the default value is "Enable idle".

You can also change your other plans after that.

After that you should do a reboot

2nd method:

Execute the following command in Powershell so you can check the current setting:

```
PowerCfg /QH | Select-String IDLEDISABLE -Context 1,6
```

You should see a 0 at the end of both index values (0x00000000).
The 0 stands for Enable-Idle, which means that idle is currently enabled.

If you want to disable idle, you can use the following script:

```
PowerCfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_PROCESSOR IDLEDISABLE 001

PowerCfg /SETACTIVE SCHEME_CURRENT

PowerCfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_PROCESSOR IDLEDISABLE 001

PowerCfg /SETACTIVE SCHEME_CURRENT
```

Afterwards you should use the command

```
PowerCfg /QH | Select-String IDLEDISABLE -Context 1,6
```

again to check if the index value has changed to 1 (0x00000001).

Otherwise, to be on the safe side, restart the PC.

I don't know why the IdleDisable was necessary and if it was game relevant, but
you can also describe your problem here so that they can help you as good as possible.